# Multiple Models Through Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've searched and tried many a times before actually asking this question as I know how often this comes up across various websites.

However I'm dumbstruck, or just dumb, probably the latter. I currently have 4 Models, which I know I need to combine into a ViewModel.

```
namespace AssetRegistration.Models
{
    public class ComboClassViewModel
    {
        public List<AttributeType> AttributeType { get; set; }
        public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public List<Make> Makes { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above my attempt at that ViewModel, just to make sure that's correct thus far here is one of Models it uses. Note: This Model was created by scaffolding from an SQL Server's Database. All the other 3 Models follow this same look.

```
namespace AssetRegistration.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AttributeType
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",     "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AttributeType()
        {
            this.Attributes = new HashSet<Attribute>();
        }

        public System.Guid AttributeTypeID { get; set; }
        public string AttributeType1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",     "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap tabs on my main home page Index.cshtml, each tab then uses a:
    @Html.Partial("") 
to render each models corresponding page.

Here is an example of one of these partials:

```
@model AssetRegistration.Models.ComboClassViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2> 
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Attribute Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Created
        </th>
        <th></th>
   </tr>

    @foreach (var attribute in Model.AttributeType) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => attribute.AttributeType1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => attribute.DateCreated)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=attribute.AttributeTypeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=attribute.AttributeTypeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=attribute.AttributeTypeID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    } 
    </table>
```

I need some helpful guidance, I'm currently a Trainee Programmer so my knowledge is limited, please try bear that in mind when responding, although I will try my best to keep up with you.

TL;DR I need help getting multiple models to different partial views, from one singular page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the model to the view is something that begins in the controller.  And it depends on how your views are structured.  For example...

If you have a single request to a server-side action and the partial views are rendered in the parent view at that time, then your server-side action would instantiate your view model and populate it in some way:

```
var model = new ComboClassViewModel();
// set all of its properties here
return View(model);
```

Then in your parent view you would supply individual models to the partial views.  Since your sub-models are collections, I assume you'd be rendering them in a loop?  Something like this?:

```
@foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
    Html.Partial("SomeLocationPartialView", location)
```

**On the other hand**, if your parent view is just a kind of shell which itself doesn't need the data, but there will be AJAX calls which fetch the sub-models, then you don't need the overall view model in the first place.  The AJAX calls would invoke individual action methods which would return their own model instance with their own partial view.  Something like this in their own controller actions:

```
var model = new Location();
// set its properties here
return PartialView(model);
```

It really depends on how your page interacts with the server, whether all of the data comes back in a single request or whether the initial request is for a page which itself will make more requests.

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer, sometimes it's all that's needed to make it easier, thank you again, very appreciative. :)

Comment: As a last thing, when you say set all of its properties (in your first code-block), were you imagining something like this? Or I have I got the wrong end of the stick if you catch my meaning? 
           ' var model = new ComboClassViewModel();
            model.AttributeType = new List<AttributeType>();
            model.Locations = new List<Location>();
            model.Makes = new List<Make>();
            model.Users = new List<User>();
            return View(model);'

I have a feeling you meant something slightly different that's all. :)

Comment: @Callum: Well, setting the properties to empty lists should probably be done in the object's constructor, that way consuming code never needs to initialize those fields.  But whatever *values* need to go in those fields (the actual elements to add to the list, rather than just empty lists) would need to be set, yes.